# Add the option null to the dropdown dynamic in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have added a dropdown dynamic in codeigniter

```
echo form_dropdown('mydrop',$options);
```

The options are called of a query in the database.  How can I add at first of the options, the option:

```
value="" Select an option with codeigniter
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [union](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) operator

```
$newoptions = array('0' => 'Select an option') + $options;
```

`echo form_dropdown('mydrop',$newoptions)`;